# Rails: sortable has_and_belongs_to_many relationships

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery-ui, sorting, has-and-belongs-to-many

Given this relationship:

```
class Doc < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :articles
end
```

and

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :docs 
end
```

How would you approach sorting the `articles` in the Doc with jQuery UI? I was following [this](http://railscasts.com/episodes/147-sortable-lists-revised?view=asciicast) tutorial, which was all well and good until it came time to run this migration:

```
rails g migration add_position_to_faqs position:integer
```

because it seems like doubling-up when I already have a relationship table, thus:

```
create_table "articles_docs", :id => false, :force => true do |t|
  t.integer "article_id"
  t.integer "doc_id"
end

add_index "articles_docs", ["article_id", "doc_id"], :name => "index_articles_docs_on_article_id_and_doc_id", :unique => true
```

Any thoughts at all? Not really understanding the relationship table isn't helping me figure this out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `has_many :through` instead of `has_and_belongs_to_many`. That will give you an intermediary model to hold the position column, and you'll sort *those* rather than sorting the articles.

Comment: Do you know of any resources or tutorials for a conversion? Everything I can find seems kinda dated and/or unclear.

Comment: I don't know of any good tutorials, but it's usually a very simple process. Generate a new model for the join, add the two belongs_to associations to it, change your has_and_belongs_to_manys into has_many :throughs, then fix your migrations (migrate down, delete the habtm migration, then migrate up).